# Why does this user-agent keep asking for favicon.ico and nothing else

Tags: user-agent, favicon

Of all the things that I'd think a UA would cache it would be a favicon.  One useragens seems to request it every 5 to 10 minutes

```
Safari5531.9 CFNetwork/438.14 Darwin/9.8.0 (i386) (MacBookPro5%2C1)
```

I will assume that this is a MacBookPro 5.1 running Safari 4.02, but what does is it doing with that favicon that it has to request it so often?

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's just the nature of a browser to often request the favicon.ico file for whatever reason, whether or not it even exists.

Comment: With old versions of IE (I think 5.5?) you could tell if you had been bookmarked by looking for these types of requests.  Is the same thing happening here?